# Can MOSFET exceed breakdown voltage without being permanently damaged?

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, switching, specifications

I just have a simple question that I can't find a simple answer to anywhere.

Is it possible to exceed the breakdown voltage of a power MOSFET (to short circuit it) without causing permanent damage?

Thanks!

Comment: Anything exceeding the specs is not guaranteed. (its not guaranteed to work, its also not guaranteed to fail, so it might work for some units). Also, to short a FET doesn't sound like exceeding its voltage. Perhaps best thing would be to provide a schematic.

Comment: As long as you keep the current very low…

Comment: if you exceed the drain source breakdown with the FET off, it will avalanche. if you limit the avalanche current with eg. a megaohm resistor, nothing bad should happen.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you violate the gate-source or gate-drain voltage limits you may destroy the MOSFET even if the current is limited to a low value.

Comment: @eescott please change your question from "is it possible" to something more specific.

Comment: Why, what did you have in mind? I find the question ambiguous, but if I knew why you were asking maybe I could give you a better answer.

Answer (score 15):

Many MOSFETs are characterized to allow overvoltage and the subsequent breakdown of drain to source provided the energy limits in avalanche are not exceeded. Provided you don't exceed these limits the device will not be damaged and will perform to the manufacturer's specification.

For example, this is a section of an IRFP254PBF power FET datasheet.

Both single event and repetitive event energies are listed. Provided you meet these limits the device will not be damaged.

[IRFP254PBF Datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/427/91214-1768458.pdf)

[image]

Comment: what about a constant power breakdown? I.E. what if I was going to test MOSFET's breakdown by applying a voltage source with a current limit of 250uA (which is what the datasheet usually qualifies as a breakdown), and I slowly ramped the voltage up to the power supply current limit? A 100V FET at that point would be burning 25mW in breakdown constantly. Is that bad?

Comment: @Nino - I expect that would be ok. A couple of caveats - the actual breakdown voltage may be much, much higher than the rated voltage (ie more than 100V for a 100V part). Also the breakdown may only be occurring in a small section of the die so the power capability will probably be much lower than the rated dissipation of the device.

Comment: I totally agree with your first point. In fact, if I do this on a 100V FET I have in house, it goes to 124V before breaking down. Your second point is what I am trying to get more clarity on. In the datasheet you linked, they specify 250uA as the breakdown voltage current. I wonder does that mean it is designed as such only or tested as such at the end of the production line... I wonder if this type of testing is safe. The context is a company I work with just did this testing on a bunch of FETs without telling us and it slightly worries me.

Comment: @Nino - I would expect that the 250uA is just a test condition definition that allows easy testing and probably bears little relation to the device capability. This application note gives some information but doesn't answer the questions - https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/Vishay_AN861.pdf